# Access 2013 - Update datasheet with different criterias for each columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with about 20 columns and about 3000 rows, some fields are blank. This database is **generated automatically** and the information can change.

Example:

```
   | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |   ...    | Column 20 |   
1  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   BBB    |          |    BBB    |
2  |          |   BBB    |   BBB    |   BBB    |    BBB    |
3  |  BBB     |          |          |   BBB    |    BBB    |
4  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   BBB    |   BBB    |           |
5  |  BBB     |   BBB    |          |   BBB    |    BBB    |
```

I'm going to use this one to update another existing table that I have to input manually the missing data

```
   | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |   ...    | Column 20 |   
1  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   BBB    |          |   4444    |
2  |  AAA     |   BBB    |  4444    |   BBB    |   4444    |
3  |  BBB     |   AAA    |   BBB    |   BBB    |    BBB    |
4  | 4444     |   BBB    |   BBB    |   BBB    |           |
5  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   AAA    |   BBB    |    BBB    |
```

As you can see, we have some situations:
1 - The information in the actual and update table is the same **(OK)**
2 - Information in both table is missing **(OK)**
3 - New information in the update table **(OK)**
4 - In the table I'm going to use to update information, there is still blank fields that in the actual table I've already filled.

The point is: I don't want to mess that information, so I need to create a update query that won't overwrite information with blank fields. But I need to do this with each column (Column 1 updates Column 1, Column 2 updates Column 2...)

The results should be something like this:

```
   | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |   ...    | Column 20 |   
1  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   BBB    |          |    BBB    |
2  |  AAA     |   BBB    |   BBB    |   BBB    |    BBB    |
3  |  BBB     |   AAA    |   BBB    |   BBB    |    BBB    |
4  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   BBB    |   BBB    |           |
5  |  BBB     |   BBB    |   AAA    |   BBB    |    BBB    |
```

Thanks!

Comment: Run 20 UPDATE actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use **one** query with conditional `IIF` logic without any `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE UpdateTable UT 
INNER JOIN ActualTable AT ON AT.Id = UT.Id
SET AT.[Column 1] = IIF(UT.[Column 1] IS NOT NULL, UT.[Column 1], AT.[Column 1]),
    AT.[Column 2] = IIF(UT.[Column 2] IS NOT NULL, UT.[Column 2], AT.[Column 2]),
    AT.[Column 3] = IIF(UT.[Column 3] IS NOT NULL, UT.[Column 3], AT.[Column 3]),
    ...other columns...
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @June7 mentioned in his comment, you need to create 20 update statements as follows

```
Update AT SET AT.[ColumnName] = UT.[ColumnName] 
From UpdateTable UT INNER JOIN ActualTable AT
On AT.Id = UT.Id
WHERE UT.[ColumnName] is not NULL
```

As you can see, the 20 statements will be almost identical except for the column name. This makes it easy to accelerate the solution by one of the following options

- Create a dynamic sql query to which you pass column name from your code
- Copy and paste the same query 20 times to a text editor and just replace column name

Comment: This query is not valid in MS Access SQL as the dialect does not support `FROM` inside an `UPDATE` query.